# SwiftUI　Steppperのvalueをバインディングできない

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, swift5

## わからないこと

ViewModelにある`Drink`の`drink.cups`と`Stepper`の値をバインディングしたいです。

SwiftUIを用いて、Stepperを使おうとしたのですが
61行目のようにStepperを使おうとすると

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Published<UInt>.Publisher' to expected argument type 'Binding<_>'
```

とエラーが出てしまいます。

## 環境

- Xcode 11.3
- Swift 5.13

## ソースコード

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine


class Drink: ObservableObject, Identifiable {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    let id: String = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String //名前
    let one_of_caffein_amount: float_t //一杯あたりのカフェインの量[mg]
    @Published var cups: UInt //個数

    init(name: String, cups: UInt, one_of_caffein_amount: float_t) {
        self.name = name
        self.one_of_caffein_amount = one_of_caffein_amount
        self.cups = 0
    }

}


final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var caffein_amuont_sum: float_t = 0
    @Published var drinks: [Drink] = [
        .init(name: "インスタントコーヒー", cups: 0, one_of_caffein_amount: 108.0),
        .init(name: "缶コーヒー", cups: 0, one_of_caffein_amount: 40.0),
        .init(name: "紅茶", cups: 0, one_of_caffein_amount: 45.0),
    ]


    func Addcaffein(drink: Drink) {
        caffein_amuont_sum += drink.one_of_caffein_amount
    }

    func Removecaffein(drink: Drink) {
        caffein_amuont_sum -= drink.one_of_caffein_amount
    }
}


//セル
struct DrinkItem: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    var drink: Drink

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(drink.name)
            Spacer()

　　　　　　　//ERROR!!
            Stepper(value: drink.$cups, in: 0 ... 99, label:  {Text(" \(drink.$cups) 個")})　
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3.0, leading: 20.0, bottom: 3.0, trailing: 20.0))
    }
}


//全体
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("計 0g")
            Spacer()
            List(viewModel.drinks) { drink in
                DrinkItem(viewModel: self.viewModel, drink: drink)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Caffein Checker", displayMode:  .inline)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: ContentViewModel())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DrinkItem`の`var drink: Drink`を`@State`か`@ObservedObject`にして、

```
Stepper(value: $drink.cups, in: 0...99, label: { Text(" \(drink.cups) 個") })
```

上のように書く（Bindingの方は`$drink.cups`、labelクロージャ内の普通に参照するのは`$`を付けずに`drink.cups`）必要があります。